# simple sign up page using bootstrap and validating using Jquery and bootstrapvalidator , i want to call modal after validation success

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

[Image 1[][Image 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juRUZ.png)In my form, I have added some validation using jquery and bootstrap validator. After validation, I need to display success message on modal popup. My coding is as follow:
    `
    
    
    
    
    Bootstrap form Validation

## Bootstrap form Validation

Full Name:
                    
                
                
                     Password 
                    
                
                
                     Confirm Password
                    
                
                
                     E-mail :
                    
                
                
                    Date of Birth 
                        
                            
                                
                        
                
                
                     submit

```
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Success</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
<script>
    var successFlag = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dateOfBirth').datepicker({
                format : 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        })
        .on('input change', function(e) {
            // Revalidate the date field
            // alert("selected date is :"+$(this).val());
           $('#validateform').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'dob');
        });
        $('#validateform').bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons:{
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields:{
                full_name: {
                    validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                            //successFlag = false,
                            min: 5,
                            message: 'please enter your full name with minimum 5 letters length'
                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            //successFlag = false,
                            message: 'please enter your full name'
                        }
                    }
                },
                password: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            //successFlag = false,
                            message: 'enter your password'
                        }
                    }
                },
                confirmPassword:{
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            //successFlag = false,
                            message: 'enter your password'
                        },
                        identical: {
                            //successFlag = false,
                            field: 'password',
                            message: ' enter similar password'
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    validators:{
                        notEmpty:{
                            //successFlag = false,
                            message:'please enter your email address'
                        },
                        emailAddress:{
                            //successFlag = false,
                            message:'please enter a valid email address'
                        }
                    }
                },
                dob: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            //successFlag = false,
                            message: 'The date is required'
                        },
                        date: {
                            //successFlag = false,
                            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                            message: 'The date is not a valid'
                        }
                    }   
                },
            },
            onSuccess: function(e, data) {
                        //this section before submit
                        alert(successFlag);
                        successFlag = true;
                        alert(successFlag);
                        $('.modalMy').modal('show');
                    }
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>'
```

And if any one know validation on age based on date of birth. i.e i should consider the age group between 14 and 50 if rest is given it should show error.

Comment: I don't see where you've applied `modalMy` to your actual modal, but I think some of your code is missing.  Are you receiving any errors when viewing the console?  Regarding your age range Date Picker allows you to specify a min/max Date.  You could pretty easily apply that to prohibit anyone younger than 14 or older than 50... though the latter opens you up to a host of legal concerns depending on the country.

Comment: <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class = "btn btn-success btn-block" id="sub"> submit </button>
       </div>
       <div id="myModal" class="modal fade modalMy" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog"> Hi as above i had applied @Robert C , my main aim is to call modal after the validation is successful. i actually pasted complete code but it is missing in above details, dont know why, and no run time error's are shown. plus for date validation in min and max can i jut write today -14 and today -50 so that i no need to change validation daily.. thank you

Comment: @Robert C please find attached images for the code before it shows. Thanks for your response